# How to get facebook share count from New Graph API v2.7

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Facebook rest API has deprecated now.
Facebook*: https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%%URL%%&format=json

So how can I get Facebook share count for my website.

New Graph API v2.7

Answer (score 0):

Please use this bellow code.
Create app id for your website and call share page URL it will return share count.
You can use curl library for retrieve data form Facebook

$json_string = file_get_contents_curl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?id=http://example.com/xyz/&access_token=123456789002599|abcdSXS_PJNQ5iEBH098_ABC");

$json = json_decode($json_string, true);

echo $json['share']['share_count']

Curl code`private function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
        $cont = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $cont;
    }`